# sitefinity parameters ActionResult method

Tags: sitefinity

I have widget where I like to call the a custom ActionResult method? can I do that in the
widget properties?

public string ActionResultName { get; set; }

public ActionResult Edit()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edit method will be automatically called when you visit the /yourPage/edit url.

or if you are inside another action method, like Index, you can do RedirectToAction("Edit").